# Why does vmovapd cause segfault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, vectorization, sse, memory-alignment, avx

I have allocated an array of doubles aligned to 32 bytes with

```
double *dst;
posix_memalign((void**)&dst, 32, 4*sizeof(double));
```

I later use `_mm256_store_pd(dst,q);` and get occasional segfaults at the instruction

```
vmovapd YMMWORD PTR [rdi],ymm0
```

Why does a segfault occur here? Can `vmovapd` cause a segfault for a reason other than alignment?

Comment: `Can vmovapd cause a segfault for a reason other than alignment?`  Yes, on NULL pointers (or other invalid accesses).  Use a debugger and look at RDI at the point where it faults to see whether it was misaligned or simply invalid.  (Try using gdb's `x` command to dump the memory there.  If gdb says invalid access, then you know it's a bad pointer even if it's aligned.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I checked that the pointers were valid. I examined a core dump and found that I was passing a misaligned pointer in one case.

Answer (score 2):

There was an error elsewhere in the code that caused a misaligned pointer to be used. As Peter Cordes pointed out, another reason could have been an invalid pointer.